# How to catch exception(Inner Exception) raised from SQL Server in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, exception

I want to catch INNER Exception raised from SQL SERVER and show that exception in MessegeBox  in WPF

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Catch the OUTER exception and use the `InnerException` property?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here one of the method you can use:

```
        try
        {
            //Some commands that can raise an exception
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Exception inner = e.InnerException ?? e;
            while (inner.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = inner.InnerException;
            }
            //inner exception will contain the innerest exception

        }
```

Comment: how we find the type of exception that raised from SQL SERVER??

Comment: Exception is the base class for all exceptions. I think that SqlException class is the base class for sql server exeptions.

Comment: This will fail in a lot of cases.  It's better to write an extension class that recursively finds the innermost exception.

Comment: Which cases do you mean? You must try to avoid recursion where possible.